# Change 3rd party module for Angular

Tags: angular, module

I imported a 3rd party module into my Angular 4 application (angular2-tag-input), and I need to change something in the module's code. I did the changes, I can see them if I run `ng serve` but if I run it wit `--prod`, or if I build it and publish it, I see the original module. What am I doing wrong?

I'm only changing some styles, in the *ts files of the module, and I can't overwrite from outside, I've tried.

Comment: You can fork the GitHub repo, modify it and use that instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but that defeats the purpose of modules..